# When exactly does <afile> differ from <amatch>?

Tags: autocmd

The [documentation](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%3A%3Camatch%3E) says:

```
<afile>    When executing autocommands, is replaced with the file name
           for a file read or write.
<abuf>     When executing autocommands, is replaced with the currently
           effective buffer number (for ":r file" and ":so file" it is
           the current buffer, the file being read/sourced is not in a
           buffer).
<amatch>   When executing autocommands, is replaced with the match for
           which this autocommand was executed.  It differs from
           <afile> only when the file name isn't used to match with
           (for FileType, Syntax and SpellFileMissing events).
```

Yet, if I had this `autocmd`:

```
autocmd BufNewFile * echo expand('<amatch>') expand('<afile>')
```

And opened, say `.zshrc` in `/tmp` (`cd /tmp; vim .zshrc`), I get:

```
/tmp/.zshrc .zshrc
```

They are not the same. What's going on?

`%` is faithful to what I actually typed. `vim ./.zshrc` with `expand('%')` added to the above `autocmd` gives me:

```
/tmp/.zshrc .zshrc ./.zshrc
```

Comment: Do you think the difference can be that `<afile>` is only the filename whereas `<amatch>` is the complete path for the file ?

Comment: @Nobe4 yes, that's *always* how it turns out. `%`, however, is faithful to whatever I actually mentioned. But I'm not sure I can trust `%` here. :/

Comment: If you type `vim /tmp/.zshrc` they're the same strings. If your cwd is `/tmp` you will get an absolute path, and a relative path, and while they are not the same strings, they are the same paths.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I typed just plain `vim .zshrc`

Comment: In expand you can have : `expand('<amatch>') == expand('%:p')` and `expand('<afile>') == expand('%')` . What do you think ? Edit: Just saw your edition, the `expand('<afile>') == expand('%')` doesn't apply anymore

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure but isn't `<amatch>` the pattern match of the autocmd? If you use `BufNewFile` it will be the filename; apparently absolute from your examples. For `FileType` it should then be the matched file type: `zsh` for your example if you replace `BufNewFile` with `FileType`.

Comment: @tokoyami (mostly) yes. The question is, why does `<amatch>`  differ from `<afile>` in cases other than those specified in the docs? So, `FileType` is pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: @muru Ah, got it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<amatch>` is exactly what is matched against the `autocmd` pattern.  For `autocmd`s that match filenames, symlinks are resolved, the result is canonicalized, and the full path is returned.

`<afile>` is the canonical full path as above, but the result is also shortened, which is essentially the same as `fnamemodify(file, ':.')` (the exact details are more involved, but the preceding description is accurate for all "normal" cases).

Thus, in general `expand('<afile>') == expand('<amatch>:.')` (**edit:** provided, of course, that they do refer to the same thing).

Comment: That seems to be the behaviour, yes. But do you have anything to support this answer?

Comment: @muru: You mean, other than my good looks and my perfect smile? ;) Yeah, I think I do: [<afile>](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/8060687905bdadc46abb68ee6d40e5660e352297/src/ex_docmd.c#L10623-L10640) and [<amatch>](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/8060687905bdadc46abb68ee6d40e5660e352297/src/ex_docmd.c#L10652-L10659) sources.

Comment: In general, afile is not the same as amatch, as it can quite be different depending on the autocommand event.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Yes. The point of the question is, they can _still_ be different for `autocmd`s where `<afile>` and `<amatch>` _do_ refer to the same thing (namely, to a file), contrary to what the manual implies.  My answer explains how and why they differ in that particular case.  Better now? :)